# Why does this error appear me on sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I create the table "Funcionario"
but then the tables "Viagem" and "Encomenda"
show me this error. I didn't understand why, can somebody help me? i can share all the script if you want to see all.
The error that appears is :

> "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.
>
> A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a
>   column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key
>   constraint in the referenced table.

[EDIT] SCRIPT

```
-- Criar Tabela Zona Geografica

CREATE TABLE ZonaGeografica(
id_zona_geo INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_ZonaGeografica_id_zona_geo PRIMARY KEY,
latitude INTEGER NOT NULL,
longitude INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- Criar Tabela Armazem

CREATE TABLE Armazem(
cod_armazem INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_Armazem_cod_armazem PRIMARY KEY,
id_zona_geo INTEGER NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
morada VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_ZonaGeografica_id_zona_geo FOREIGN KEY (id_zona_geo) REFERENCES ZonaGeografica(id_zona_geo)
);

-- Criar Tabela TipoVeiculo

CREATE TABLE TipoVeiculo(
tipo_veiculo VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT pk_TipoVeiculo_tipo_veiculo PRIMARY KEY,
capacidade_volume INTEGER NOT NULL,
capacidade_peso INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- Criar Tabela Veiculo

CREATE TABLE Veiculo(
cod_veiculo INTEGER NOT NULL,
tipo_veiculo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
matricula VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
marca VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
modelo VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
nr_apolice INTEGER NOT NULL,
nr_quilometros INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Veiculo_cod_veiculo_tipo_veiculo PRIMARY KEY(cod_veiculo, tipo_veiculo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Veiculo_tipo_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (tipo_veiculo) REFERENCES TipoVeiculo(tipo_veiculo),
CONSTRAINT ck_Veiculo_matricula CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(matricula ,'[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'))
);

-- Criar Tabela Funcionario

CREATE TABLE Funcionario(
id_func INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_Funcionario_id_func PRIMARY KEY,
id_tipo INTEGER NOT NULL,
cod_armazem INTEGER NOT NULL,
cod_supervisor INTEGER NOT NULL,
cc INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ck_Funcionario_cc CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cc ,'[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1}-[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}')),
nome_func VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
morada_func VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
nif_func INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ck_Funcionario_nif_func CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(nif_func ,'[0-9]{7}')),
salario_mensal NUMERIC(*,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Funcionario_id_tipo FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES Categoria(id_tipo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Funcionario_cod_armazem FOREIGN KEY (cod_armazem) REFERENCES Armazem(cod_armazem),
CONSTRAINT fk_Funcionario_cod_supervisor FOREIGN KEY (cod_supervisor) REFERENCES Funcionario(id_func)
);

-- Criar Tabela Categoria

CREATE TABLE Categoria(
id_tipo INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_Categoria_id_tipo PRIMARY KEY,
tipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

-- Criar Tabela Viagem


CREATE TABLE Viagem(
nr_viagem INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_Viagem_nr_viagem PRIMARY KEY,
id_tipo INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_func INTEGER NOT NULL,
cod_veiculo INTEGER NOT NULL,
tipo_veiculo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
data_partida DATE NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_id_tipo FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES Categoria(id_tipo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_id_func FOREIGN KEY (id_func) REFERENCES Funcionario(id_func),
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_tipo_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (tipo_veiculo) REFERENCES TipoVeiculo(tipo_veiculo)
);


-- Criar Tabela Encomenda

CREATE TABLE Encomenda(
id_encomenda INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_Encomenda_id_encomenda PRIMARY KEY,
cod_armazem INTEGER NOT NULL,
cod_veiculo INTEGER NOT NULL,
nr_viagem INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_nr_viagem FOREIGN KEY (nr_viagem) REFERENCES Viagem(nr_viagem),
id_func INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_cod_armazem FOREIGN KEY (cod_armazem) REFERENCES Armazem(cod_armazem),
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_id_func FOREIGN KEY (id_func) REFERENCES Funcionario(id_func)
);
```

Comment: Put the code as text in the question.  Your images are too small to read.

Comment: We don't know how "veiculo" and "tipoveiculo" tables look like, so - difficult to guess what's wrong. Do post ALL CREATE TABLE statements. BTW, there's no need to declare a column NOT NULL if it is a primary key.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you cannot reference as foreign key a column that is not unique. If they are not `PRIMARY KEY`s, then make them `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @Littlefoot there it is

Comment: Kaushik has just said what's wrong; have a look at his answer.

Comment: Instead of posting a long script here you could have run each statement individually. Then you would know which foreign key had actually failed, which would make for an easier diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's wrong

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo)
```

For table Viagem you have this `FOREIGN KEY` which is referring to only a part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY` in `Veiculo (cod_veiculo, tipo_veiculo)`

same with this for `Encomenda`

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY(cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo)
```

**Fix** your design such that a `FOREIGN KEY` combination **matches** with a `UNIQUE KEY/PRIMARY KEY` in the referenced tables.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is fairly clear (or at least better than some); you have a foreign key which tries to reference column(s) that don't form a unique or primary key in the parent table.

In `Viagem` you have:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo),
```

but the primary key in `Veiculo` is the combination of two columns:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_Veiculo_cod_veiculo_tipo_veiculo PRIMARY KEY(cod_veiculo, tipo_veiculo),
```

You can't reference a single column from that key, as that single column won't be unique on its own, leading to ambiguity. So the obvious (but probably wrong) fix is to change `Viagem` to reference both columns:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Viagem_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo, tipo_veiculo)
  REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo, tipo_veiculo),
```

(If you did that then wouldn't really need the `fk_Viagem_tipo_veiculo` constraint as well, since the `tipo_veiculo` is part of the FK to `Veiculo`, and that table already has its own FK to `TipoVeiculo`.)

But your `Encomenda` table has the same problem; you have:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Encomenda_cod_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (cod_veiculo) REFERENCES Veiculo(cod_veiculo),
```

there too. But for that table you don't have the `id_tipo` column, so you *can't* include that in the FK.

Which points to the more likely solution, via a question - why does `Veiculo` include `tipo_veiculo` in its PK at all? It looks like the `cod_veiculo` *should* be unique on its own; in which case change that PK to just:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_Veiculo_cod_veiculo_tipo_veiculo PRIMARY KEY(cod_veiculo),
```

and leave both `Viagem` and `Encomenda` as you already had them, with all their Fk referencing a single column each. (Although you may want to consider whether `Viagem` actually needs the `id_tipo` column at all, since yuo can get that from `Veiculo` via the linked `cod_veiculo`...)

If you really want to keep that PK as it is then you would have to add a seperate unique key for just `cod_veiculo`, which would then satisfy `fk_Encomenda_cod_veiculo` - but that looks wrong.